# Why my android notification all time disappear?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have problem with my notification in android I don't know what I am doing wrong...
This notification is created in my Service class(AfterBootService) and that service is launched when boot completed in my Receiver class(MyReceiver) code below of both classes:

*MyReceiver.class*

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, AfterBootService.class);
        context.startService(service);      
    }

}
```

and here *AfterBootService.class*

```
public class AfterBootService extends Service { 
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        showNotification();     
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {      
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Show a notification while this service is running.
     */
    private void showNotification() {

        int icon = R.drawable.icon_notification_ribbon;
        String tickerText = "Your Notification";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();     

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);           

        String expandedText = "Sample Text";
        String expandedTitle = "Program Name Here"; 

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, IconActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);        

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
        //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, expandedTitle, expandedText, contentIntent);               

        // Send the notification.
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
}
```

And now when I launch everything is ok receiver start service and service start the notification BUT when it show in status bar and after in notification window with proper message IT DISAPPEAR after some (2-3) seconds... I didn't set anything that allow that message to disappear (I guess so I am not expert). What I want to know:

1. How to keep that notification message all time when my service is running ?
2. It is possible to keep all time notification without running service that launched that notification ? To explain it more carefully it is possible to launch notification in service after that destroy the service with stopSelf() and still keep that notification message ?

I can paste here My Manifest if it is needed. thx

Answer (score 2):

edit your on destroy method

from:

```
    public void onDestroy() {
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

to

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

because its cancelling your notification and it will remain till user clears it ;)

you can trigger notiffication without a service from the reciver and can add

```
   notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

to set it as non clearable

Comment: Yes now it works but I made another thing wrong too now I try to explain it: My program worked but only one time and here what I made: 1.I pressed to wipe all information from virtual. 2.When wipe over I closed it and I pressed Run->MyProgram and here I've got message after all done ... .apk installed succesfully. 3. Now I pressed Window->Android AVD Manager and I launched MyVirtual after .apk installed and I've got properly working program (without missed notification). 4.I closed that Virtual and I pressed again Run->MyProgram and now what's happened I have got error (not success install).

Comment: But now when I changed code to that that U wrote even when I pressed second time Run->MyApplication I didn't got error and my .apk was installed successfuly again :). And now when I need to see how my program work I need to launch MyVirtual from Window->AVD Manager NOT FROM Run->MyAplication because I didn't made any changes and I ALREADY INSTALLED MY .APK. It was My fault before (when I searched for what I made wrong) because I pressed all time Run->MyAplication instead Window->AVD Manager and my notifications dissapeared because of that and wrong code.

Comment: Now all working like I want :) I needed to understand that I need to press and install another .apk when I make change in my code. When I didn't change anything I simple neet to go to Window->AVD Manager and simple launch MyVirtual from here. Anyway my code was wrong and Ur is good :) thx

Comment: never mention i am happy that i was able to help u.. :)